# How to normalize image to range 0 255 with PIL Lib

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, normalization

I have a problem with grayscale image normalization. OpenCV have a `cv2.normalize()` method (with parameters like in code), but I need to use **Pillow library** for reading images and numpy to do operations on them.
I need to normalize it from input range to `[0,255]`.
Here is my code but it gives bad results.

```
def disparity_normalization(self, disp): # disp is an array in uint8 data type
        # disp_norm = cv2.normalize(src=disp, dst= disp, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        _min = np.amin(disp)
        _max = np.amax(disp)
        disp_norm = disp - _min * 255.0 / (_max - _min)
        disp_norm = np.uint8(disp_norm)
        plt.imshow(disp_norm)
        plt.show()

        return disp_norm
```

EDIT:
The minimum and maximum values from the function is correct, but plots gives a bad result.

[Here is function plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8imun.png)

[Here is cv2.normalize() plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub00X.png)

Comment: what is the minimum and maximum values the function returns just now

Comment: Minimum and maximum value is correct, but the result in plot is bad. Look at EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot the parenthesis.

It probably should be:

```py
def disparity_normalization(self, disp): # disp is an array in uint8 data type
        # disp_norm = cv2.normalize(src=disp, dst= disp, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        _min = np.amin(disp)
        _max = np.amax(disp)
        #disp_norm = disp - _min * 255.0 / (_max - _min)
        disp_norm = (disp - _min) * 255.0 / (_max - _min)
        disp_norm = np.uint8(disp_norm)
        plt.imshow(disp_norm)
        plt.show()

        return disp_norm
```